# Loading a bitmap to a window

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi

I want to load a bitmap to a window in my application, I will use GDI to draw the bitmap to the window. Should I also draw the bitmap when handling the `WM_PAINT` message so that the bitmap persists on the window?

Comment: Make life easy on yourself, and *only* draw in the `WM_PAINT` handler. You'll avoid duplicating your code and introducing subtle bugs. Use [`InvalidateRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx) to force a `WM_PAINT` when you're ready to draw.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Hi, can you tell me what are these "subtle bugs" that could occur if I painted outside the `WM_PAINT` handler. The following MSDN article don't mention any bugs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @John if you paint outside of WM_PAINT, you'll find your changes being erased when something else causes WM_PAINT to repaint the window - having it go uncovered by another window, for example.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Oh, I thought that you meant by "bugs" that my program will crash or something! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should draw your bitmap in **WM_PAINT** or **WM_ERASEBKGND** handler just like this:

```
        switch(Msg)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

            // Load the bitmap from the resource
            bmp = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MY_COOL_PIC));
            // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
            MemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            // Select the new bitmap
            HBITMAP hOldBmp = SelectObject(MemDC, bmp);

            // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
            BitBlt(hDC, 10, 10, 450, 400, MemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            // Restore the old bitmap
            SelectObject(MemDC, hOldBmp);
            DeleteObject(bmp);

            DeleteDC(MemDC);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

Comment: Don't delete a DC while you still have objects selected into it. Unselect `bmp` prior to calling `DeleteDC(MemDC)`.